# Recognizing instances placed on the stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I'm working with **Flash Builder 4.6** as an IDE and **Flash CS5.5** to create library items.
The problem is - when I put an instance of a library item on the stage or inside of another item, Flash Builder fails to detect the *instance name* that was declared in Flash CS.
**This doesn't prevent the code from compiling just fine though.**

I understand that the IDE only sees the fields that I have declared directly in the `.as` file, but it really hinders me that I the IDE goes crazy when I do this.

Is there any way to circumvent this - other than dynamically creating and placing the instances?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you compile the flash library as a .swc?

Comment: @RIAstar I simply created a Flash CS project and a Flash Builder project at the same folder - and simply use the Flash Builder to edit the `.as` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty old question, I've since found an answer a long time ago.

The way to do this is to set "Automatically Declare stage instances" to false in Flash CS, and use the following syntax:

```
public var instanceName:Type;
```

The variable name and type must correspond to the object placed on the stage and it will be populated automatically on constructor call. (like a normal field.)

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with using the name you have given as instance name. Flash Builder will not identify or list it with others when you press CTRL + SPACE. You need to worry only when it shows compile errors.

One thing usually done is creating proxy variables for the library items on stage.

Suppose you have a library item `Car` which you dragged and dropped on stage in Flash CS 5 and gave it instance name `car1`. In your .as file you can create a proxy variable in the constructor and use that proxy variable everywhere else in the code.

```
var car1Proxy:MovieClip = MovieClip(car1);
```